# How to: inster into select in c# oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, select, insert, sql-insert

I have a method which has to copy a row.

```
        private void NewGhostPerson(int copiedPersonID, string newName) {
            using (var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();                
                string SQL = @"  Insert into Personal 
                    (ID,NAME,City,Value,Status,department) 
                    select IND_ID_00_SQ.NextVal,:pName,City,Value,0,department
                    from Personal 
                    where SATIRNO=:pID";
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                cmd.CommandText = SQL;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pName", newName));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pID", copiedPersonID));
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

This method's query works at oracle SQL Developer. But When I debug method, this query runs but doesnt record anything. And doesnt show any error.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can simply use `cmd.Parameters.Add("pName", newName);`, however I prefer `cmd.Parameters.Add("pName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = newName;`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thank you. I tried that way too. but still change nothing

Comment: Do you get any error when you use `try {cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();} catch ()..`

Comment: there is no error